# Dividing cells of an array into bins in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have the following cells in an array called `Segments`:

```
319x3 double
319x3 double
319x3 double
319x3 double
319x3 double
319x3 double
319x3 double
319x3 double
319x3 double
319x3 double
```

As you see, each cell contains 319 for each of three axes (X, Y and Z).  I would like to count the 'n bin histogram' (size of the n=10) for each axis in the cell.

I have written the following statement.  However, the original goal of this statement was the count of 'n bin histogram' for all three axes (e.g.`[26,218,154,169,70,11,92,119,73,25]`), and I want to get **'n bin histogram'** for each single axis in the cell.

Comment: What do you mean by n bin histogram? Is it top 10 or bins that are hit 10 times or first 10 ?

Comment: What is the value of `nn` in your statements? Also, `Segments` is a cell array. As far as I can tell, the statement `histcounts(Segments{nn(:,)},10)` should produce an error since the output of `Segments{nn(:,1)}` will be a list of 10 arguments. If you can be more specific about what you're trying to achieve and give a runnable example (if not running, report the error) that demonstrates the problem, it would make answering this question a great deal easier.

Comment: Dear Alexander, thanks for you comment. first, I have 34 segments        (each segment contains the acceleration data of three axes (319 of  x data, 319 of y data,  and 319 of z data).  i want  to extract set of features from the raw data ( one of these features is Binned Distribution (30):  Relative histogram distribution in linear spaced bins between the minimum and the maximum acceleration in the segment. Ten bins were used (each axis)). i dont know how to add runnable  code?